# Can I delete an object without deleting any of its attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

eg.

```
post = Post.first

post.image_path #(this is a image path like http://localhost:3000/uploads/image/sd54asdf.jpg)
```

if I doing:

```
post.destroy
```

With this, I destroy every attributes from post object including the image.

Can I delete object without delete the image?

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

With this method, I check if is the last object referenced by the image.

```
def validates_image_dependents
  post = self.find(params[:id])
   i=0
  for this_post in Post.all
   if this_post.posted_filename == post.post_filename
    i+=1
   end
  end
 return i > 1
end
```

Comment: if Post has_one image then using delete instead of destroy would have done the job.

Comment: Thank you @AlokSwain , could you help me with a example?. Thank you :D

Comment: With the delete method does not delete the image and it does works fine. This is correct? Thank you @AlokSwain

Comment: This is correct and works fine in console, but in rails does not works :(. Im sorry I close this question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling destroy on a record is going to delete all data relating to that record.  I think that you have 3 options:

1. Make an associated object that contains information about the image and do not set up Rails to delete the associated records when a Post is deleted
2. I suspect this is more like what you're trying to achieve - Instead of destroying objects you may still need to reference, update the Post model to have a boolean that tracks whether the record is "deleted" and then use this to only retrieve active posts.  This is soft-deleting and is very common where complex associations make it hard to totally delete records
3. Set up the destroy action to create some sort of archived post record that you can use to access the attributes you still require

I like option 2 but it depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have many objects that share the same image with carrierwave. My problem is that, I want only delete the image if is the last object or the uniqueness that use this image. But if I there is 2 or more objects with the same image I dont want delete the image.

Comment: Then I think you definitely need to separate your images out from your posts.  I'm not sure whether the dependent option on the association can achieve what you need or whether you'd need to put an after_destroy callback on Post to manually check whether the Image needs deleting.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick, but how I can check with a callback `after_destroy :validates_image_dependents` that the image has not been deleted, depending on whether this method returns true or false.

Comment: If you've got an association so that Image has_many Posts then store the image in @post_image before you destroy the post and then in the callback delete the image only if `@post_image.posts.length == 0`?

Comment: Like I say I think you *might* be able to handle this with dependent but I've no experience of doing it myself.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. I have use **post.delete** instead of **post.destroy** and now working fine the image is not destroyed :D. this is correct?

Comment: This is correct and works fine in console, but in rails does not works :(. Im sorry I close this question :(

Comment: The delete instead of destroy suggestion was from Alok Swain not me.

Comment: Thank you, I will go try with this method. Where can I hire people for this job? Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7498/discussion-between-hyperrjas-and-nick)